# Which card will it be?

Tags: probability

A box contains five cards numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Three cards are selected at random
without replacement from the box. What’s the probability that 4 is the largest value
selected?

So i have 5 cards and i can only pick 3 one of which has to be 4. If i was allowed to pick from all 5 the probability would be 1/5 but since i can only pick 3 does that make it 1/3. or should i remove 5 as a possibility all together since 4 is highest i should get? I don't think I'm right any help?

Comment: First, think about how many ways there are to draw 3 cards from 5:  1,2,3; 1,2,4; 1,2,5; etc.  Then figure out how many of those have 4 as the largest card.

Comment: You might also note that you will be leaving two cards in the box: one of which must be the $5$ and the other must not be the $4$

Comment: Since $\binom53=10$ is _rather small_, I'd suggest exploring by brute force, then see if you could draw conclusions from your observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by:

"If i was allowed to pick from all 5 the probability would be 1/5"

Huh?  You *are* picking from all 5 ...  and why would that mean the probability is 1/5?

Likewise:

"since I can only pick 3 that makes it 1/3"

Huh? why would the number of cards that you pick determine the probability of getting 4 as the highest?  Would this also have been your answer if the question would have been what the probability is that the 5 is the highest when picking 3 cards?  Or that 2 would have been the highest?  Do you see how the answer to this question does not merely depend on the number of cards that you pick?

"or should I remove 5 as a possibility all together since 4 is the highest i should get?"

Ah, now that makes some sense! But, be careful: when you pick 3, getting a 5 was always a possibility. But yes, you cannot have a 5 as the outcome you are looking for.

So, think about the problem this way:

1. Figure out *all* possible ways you can pick 3 cards out of the 5 ... so here you should include those that include card 5
2. Figure out in how many ways you can pick 3 cards out of the 5 ... but now with 4 being the highest (which means 5 *excluded*)

Once you figure these out, simply divide the latter number by the former, and you have your probability.

For example, if it turns out that there are 20 different ways to get 3 cards out of the 5, but out of those only 12 have 4 as the highest, then the probability of getting 4 as the highest would be $\frac{12}{20}$

Of course, I just came up with some random numbers: you will have to find the actual numbers.

Comment: So i followed your recommendations and listed out all the possibilities i came up with 9 different ways to pull cards in groups of 3. I found that of the 9 only 3 groups had the number 4 as their highest value. Am i correct or should i rework my math.

Comment: 5 choose 3 is ten, so you should have found 10 ways to choose 3 cards from 5.

Comment: @Donald Close! There are 10 different ways total, not 9. But yes, 3 of those have 4 as the highest.

Comment: @Bram28 yes i see my error i forgot to list one out thank you

Comment: @Donald Cool ... so, what is the probability of getting 4 as the highest when drawing 3 cards?

Comment: So if i follow your instruction and i have 10 possible ways of pulling 3 cards from 5. Of those 10 only 3 sets have 4 as the highest value, then the probability of getting 4 as the highest value is (3/10) correct.

Comment: @Donald You got it! :)

Comment: @Bram28 Awesome! I was really over thinking the problem but thank you for simplifying it for me

Comment: @Donald You're welcome! Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Donald, if this answered your question, click the check mark to accept the answer.  I see that you’ve asked four questions on this site, but haven’t accepted any answers yet, so I’m guessing that you don’t know that’s the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [link with this problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2017_AMC_8_Problems/Problem_10) that explains it better:

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Thank you for your answer.
Can you please [edit] you answer to expand it, in order to include the main points of the link you provide? It will be more helpful both for people searching in this site and in case the link breaks. 
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[answer], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).